# How do i say something when I stand on a certain block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a map where, once you stand on lapis_block, it says this (keep in mind that you are in a bunker and just arrived):[Phillip] "Hello! you must have just arrived, have you not? Anyway, that's not important, but what is, though, is that you need your passport! Also, if you can find me my Key card, i'll give you something in return! Thank you!" It keeps saying that it can't detect Ultra_Hype (my username)! Plz help! I've seen how to make it where it kills you and stuff, but I can't make it say something!

Comment: "This is what I have" What? What do you have? You didn't actually write it.

Comment: Just a simple `/testfor @p[r=10]` > comparator > `/say Hello!...` (or whatever distance you want instead of `r=10`). The first command always active, repeat mode, the 2nd one normal. This will execute only once after finding a player and will need to be manually reset to do so another time.

Comment: I did this, and, It says the message when I'm a bit too far away when the r=2, but i can't activate it when  it's r=1, whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use the solution you saw for killing and change the command to `/say`. It should just work.

Your message is really long, so you have to execute it in a command block.

Comment: Wait a second... it's not working! This is what I put in the command:execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ lapis_block say @p [Phillip] "Hello! you must have just arrived, have you not? Anyway, that's not important, but what is, though, is that you need your passport! Also, if you can find me my Key card, i'll give you something in return! Thank you!" It till says can't detect! :'(

Comment: What exactly is the error message? And what exactly is the command you entered into the command block? You can write `\`` before and after it to draw a box around it, so that I can see more easily what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have a *Repeat* and *Always Active* command block running **/testfor @a [Co-ords]**, place a comparator and place a default command block running **/tellraw** or **/say @p [text]**. Am i not right?

Comment: You are right, but I abandoned the idea and just put a pressure plate.